# Incorrect geometric shape

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to create geometric shapes (circles) that change color depending on certain values ​​assumed by a variable.

In theory I set the values ​​of these geometric shapes so that they turn out to be circles, instead they turn out to be squares. Can you tell me why?

```
this.state = {
pressColorDx1: "",
//...
}

//....
 if (this.pressDx_p1 >= 10) { this.setState({ pressColorDx1: "#00438c" }) }
        else { this.setState({ pressColorDx1: '#afeeee' }) }

render() {
    return (
//..
<View style={{width: 15,height: 15,borderRadius: 15/2,backgroundColor: this.state.pressColorDx1,right: 30, top: 40}}></View>
)}
```

this should be a circle, but it is displayed like a square.

It's not a problem of `top` and `right`.. I have tried also b`orderRadius: 50%` and it doesn't work.

You can see there https://snack.expo.io/@keyz23/92058c

Comment: Can u share the code into [snake](http://snack.expo.io)

Comment: Check my answer again.

Comment: @DevAS look there https://snack.expo.io/@keyz23/92058c

Comment: are u solve it?

Comment: No it doesn't work ...

Comment: I checked it out at the expo
It is really round
I don't understand your problem

Comment: As you can see in the expo, the problem is when I use the backgroundColor that I have definied as this.state.color1 in Android.